# Saltstack test.ping taking 30+ seconds

Tags: salt-stack

I have essentially a barebones saltstack "cluster" running.  In fact, it's actually a master and a minion on the same host machine.

This is really a 2 part question.

1) The salt-master takes a really long time to boot.  Like 2+ minutes. The debug logs look like it's got several threads going in a loop loading/reloading configs:

```
[DEBUG   ] Reading configuration from /etc/salt/minion.d/master.conf
[DEBUG   ] Reading configuration from /etc/salt/minion.d/master.conf
[DEBUG   ] Using cached minion ID from /etc/salt/minion_id: host.my.domain
[DEBUG   ] Using cached minion ID from /etc/salt/minion_id: host.my.domain
[DEBUG   ] Reading configuration from /etc/salt/master
[DEBUG   ] Reading configuration from /etc/salt/master
[DEBUG   ] Including configuration from '/etc/salt/minion.d/master.conf'
[DEBUG   ] Reading configuration from /etc/salt/minion.d/master.conf
[DEBUG   ] Using cached minion ID from /etc/salt/minion_id: host.my.domain
[DEBUG   ] Reading configuration from /etc/salt/master
[DEBUG   ] Including configuration from '/etc/salt/minion.d/master.conf'
[DEBUG   ] Reading configuration from /etc/salt/minion.d/master.conf
[DEBUG   ] Using cached minion ID from /etc/salt/minion_id: host.my.domain
[DEBUG   ] Including configuration from '/etc/salt/minion.d/master.conf'
[DEBUG   ] Reading configuration from /etc/salt/minion.d/master.conf
[DEBUG   ] Reading configuration from /etc/salt/master
[DEBUG   ] Using cached minion ID from /etc/salt/minion_id: host.my.domain
[DEBUG   ] Reading configuration from /etc/salt/master
[DEBUG   ] LazyLoaded local_cache.clean_old_jobs
[DEBUG   ] This salt-master instance has accepted 1 minion keys.
[DEBUG   ] The `dmidecode` binary is not available on the system. GPU grains will not be available.
[DEBUG   ] The `dmidecode` binary is not available on the system. GPU grains will not be available.
[DEBUG   ] The `dmidecode` binary is not available on the system. GPU grains will not be available.
[DEBUG   ] The `dmidecode` binary is not available on the system. GPU grains will not be available.
[DEBUG   ] The `dmidecode` binary is not available on the system. GPU grains will not be available.
[DEBUG   ] MasterEvent PUB socket URI: ipc:///var/run/salt/master/master_event_pub.ipc
[DEBUG   ] MasterEvent PULL socket URI: ipc:///var/run/salt/master/master_event_pull.ipc
[DEBUG   ] MasterEvent PUB socket URI: ipc:///var/run/salt/master/master_event_pub.ipc
[DEBUG   ] MasterEvent PULL socket URI: ipc:///var/run/salt/master/master_event_pull.ipc
[DEBUG   ] MasterEvent PUB socket URI: ipc:///var/run/salt/master/master_event_pub.ipc
[DEBUG   ] MasterEvent PULL socket URI: ipc:///var/run/salt/master/master_event_pull.ipc
```

And 2) Once it finally finishes and I can auth the minion to it, just a simple test.ping is taking 30+ seconds:

```
time salt '*' test.ping

real    0m34.556s
user    0m12.230s
sys 0m0.500s
```

From the minion debug logs:

```
[DEBUG   ] Loaded minion key: /etc/salt/pki/minion/minion.pem
[DEBUG   ] Decrypting the current master AES key
[DEBUG   ] Loaded minion key: /etc/salt/pki/minion/minion.pem
[DEBUG   ] Decrypting the current master AES key
[DEBUG   ] Loaded minion key: /etc/salt/pki/minion/minion.pem
[DEBUG   ] Decrypting the current master AES key
[DEBUG   ] Loaded minion key: /etc/salt/pki/minion/minion.pem
```

This is essentially an out of the box setup with not states or anything setup. Can anyone help me address these performance issues?

Running Arch Linux on a raspberry pi, installed via the official arch repo(https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/any/salt-zmq/), version 7.2014.  These are the logs from running it manually in debug mode. There is no specific pause, it just runs in what appears to be several loops for a few minutes spewing out the above(among other things, but all generally related to loading configuration files) until it finally settles down

Comment: appended answers to bottom of initial question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running the master and minion on Raspberry Pi's - that would be your problem.

I'm on real hardware for my salt master and salt minions - I get results from the `test.ping` module in seconds.

The master starts up in seconds as well.

Comment: The Salt Minion should run just fine on a RasperryPi, but might be too resource restrained for the Salt Master.